# sql pdo fetch issue can solve it

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
$sqls =$handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM r WHERE ur= :u AND id='$id'");
$sqls->bindParam(':u',$_COOKIE['u']);
$sqls->execute();
$row  = $sqls -> fetch();

if(!($row)){
    if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['rating'] <= 5 ) {
        $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO review (b,u,r,r)      VALUES(:b,:u,:r,:r)";
        $query = $handle->prepare($sql_1); 
        $params = array(':b'=> $_POST['b'],':user'=> $_POST['u'],':r'=> $_POST[''],':ra'=> $_POST['ra']);
        $query -> execute($params); 
        echo success;
    } else {
        echo nope;
    }
    ?>
```

for some reason this doenst work i cant find any error is does not give any eror but just doenst do what i want
i dont want it to add an record if there has already been one in the database

Comment: im sorry where do you mean ?

Comment: @RahilWazir I believe it's preferred. The examples in the documentation all have the `:` prefix.

Comment: Why are you mixing parameters and variable substitution in the `SELECT` query? You should use parameters whenever possible.

Comment: do you guys know where it is going wrong ? if there is a record with ur=:u and id=$id aleardy in the database i dont want to insert but otherwise i want to insert

Comment: You have column `r` twice in the `INSERT` statement. Shouldn't the `SELECT` be `FROM review` instead of `FROM r`?

Comment: If you don't want to add a duplicate record, add a unique index on the fields, and then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE`.

Comment: yeah it should i just changed it around i didnt want to give all exact info

Comment: It's hard for us to figure out what you're doing wrong if we don't see the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your SQL: "SELECT * FROM r WHERE ur= :u AND id='$id'"
Should "SELECT * FROM r WHERE ur= ':u' AND id=$id"

```
$id=intval($_POST["id"]);
$sqls =$handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM r WHERE ur= ':u' AND id=$id");
$sqls->bindParam(':u',$_COOKIE['u']);
$sqls->execute();
$row  = $sqls -> fetch();

if(!($row)){
    if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['rating'] <= 5 ) {
        $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO review (b,u,r,r)      VALUES(':b',':u',':r',':r')";
        $query = $handle->prepare($sql_1); 
        $params = array(':b'=> $_POST['b'],':user'=> $_POST['u'],':r'=> $_POST[''],':ra'=> $_POST['ra']);
        $query -> execute($params); 
        echo success;
    } else {
        echo nope;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The Differ is between ':u' and :u.

U need quote values in INSERT Syntax and WHERE Clause.

Comment: Also u should define constants. Such as success assumed 'success'